# Question about isset($_session['username'])

Tags: php, session

I have a login page when clicked on defines the variable `$_session[username] = $name;`
this `$_session['username']` is displayed on my main page and it works fine if someone does login. however when someone does not login, the error notice:undefined index pops up. if i use

```
<?php session_start(); if($_SESSION['username']==""|| isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo "Login";}else{echo "Logout";}?>
```

i thought it would fix the problem. but it has the same error

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` ?

Comment: did not seem to work

Comment: Your if statement needs to check if the field exists before testing it.

Comment: _..did not seem to work.._ Was session username set before you tested?

Comment: @NigelRen how do i check if the field exists? sorry very new to php

Comment: @B001ᛦ its not set but i want it to check if it was set

Comment: Read @NigelRen comment

Comment: @NigelRen ahh ok i think i understand now. i think it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$_SESSION['username]` is not set, you'll receive an undefined error message.

I'd recommend using `empty()`. It's the same thing as saying `if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username] != '' )`. This is more resource intensive (minimally in your case), as it has to check if the variable isset and that it isn't empty (blank, false, 0, null, etc).

```
if( empty($_SESSION['username']) ){
    echo 'Login';
}else{
    echo 'Logout';
}
```

Comment: i have gone through a couple of other posts and saw this too. however it did not fix the issue. the same error pops up again saying undefined index: username